# HWIOBundle FacebookConnect - data pagination

Tags: facebook, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm using Symfony2 with HWIOAuthBundle. I managed to obtain requested data (including page likes), but if their number exceeds 24 and the user has more than 24 page likes facebook api sends `next` attribute with the URL to call as following:

```
...
    [24]=>
        array(4) {
          ["category"]=>
          string(26) "Computers/Internet Website"
          ["name"]=>
          string(10) "IOScreator"
          ["id"]=>
          string(16) "1488441341444225"
          ["created_time"]=>
          string(24) "2015-01-30T10:28:42+0000"
        }
      }
      ["paging"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["cursors"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["before"]=>
          string(20) "MTEyOTU3ODQ1NDAwNzAw"
          ["after"]=>
          string(24) "MTQ4ODQ0MTM0MTQ0NDIyNQ=="
        }
        ["next"]=>
        string(99) "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/10152896110784845/likes?limit=25&after=MTQ4ODQ0MTM0MTQ0NDIyNQ%3D%3D"
      }
    }
```

Does anybody know how to request the next page within this bundle?

Here is how I obtain the first response:

```
$userProvider = $this->container->get('bundleName_user.oauth_provider');
$facebookResourceOwner = $this->container->get('hwi_oauth.resource_owner.facebook');

$accessToken = $request->get('accessToken');
$userResponse = $facebookResourceOwner->getUserInformation(array(
    'access_token' => $accessToken
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of doing it directly using the bundle but HWIOBundle but there are two ways I could see you doing this.

**Option 1: Add to FacebookResourceOwner.php**

In here you could add in another function to make a request, which would use the libraries contained within HWIOBundle. Something like:

```
public function nextParamRequest($access_token, $nextURL) {
  $response = $this->httpRequest($this->normalizeUrl($nextURL, array('access_token' => $access_token), array(), array())));

  return $this->getResponseContent($response);
}
```

**Option 2: Just write your own cURL method to do it**

Somewhere in your code just add the following:

```
function curlNextUrl($access_token, $nextURL) {
  $request_url = $nextURL."&access_token=".$access_token;

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  return json_decode($response, true);
}
```